# How to interpret high P-value and low Mcnemar's Test P-value in Caret R?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, p-value, interpretation, mcnemar-test

I am using the `caret` R package to evaluate machine learning models. This gives me a lot of information about different metrics. I am confused about my result why the P-value (0.998) is extremely high and the Mcnemar's Test P-value (0.004427) is very low. I don't understand what it means that there is suggest a big difference between those two metrics.

This is the Confusion Matrix and Statistics:

[image]

Could anyone please explain how to interpret these P-value results?

Comment: Î am not a caret user, but have you seen, thatthat the extemely high p-value is a single-sided/one-tailed p-value and that the accuray is lower then the No Information Rate?

Comment: @Bernhard, Thank you for your comment! Yes, I know that this model is not the best. So you mean that a two-tailed p-value would be better to use in this case?

Comment: You've skipped over the most informative output: the confusion matrix. Your dataset is very small (52 data points) and imbalanced (4 out of 52 positive examples). The model doesn't do well at all.